# Doubts on a question being closed

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

The question ["choosing a platform for a file hosting"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673065/choosing-a-platform-for-a-file-hosting) was closed today by me and other four users; I specified, as a closing reason, the question being off-topic, and yielding to possibile subjective opinions. Also, not really close-related to programming.

I was maybe overzealous when I casted my close vote, since [poster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187291/stereofrog) is a big high-rep user and should know perfectly well the rules and regulations of this site; better than me for sure.
But I was followed by four other people, so I guess I wasn't so totally wrong with this.

On one of my comment on another question by another user (question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673215/php-in-side-html-drop-down-selects/7673262#7673262)), poster asked me the reason of my close vote:

> hi, could you comment why you voted to close this one

I don't know if discussing this kind of problem in a totally unrelated context is allowed to do or not on SO (I doubt it, though), so I decided to bring the matter under the trial of meta.

I'm just here to ask if my decision is really wrong, or if the question was actually a true Off-Topic question, and what do I need to do in the event of a user following someone else asking for clarifications.

**Edit/Update:**

Looks like something strange is happening to the poor guy. I don't know if he just got mad for this question (I doubt it), or someone  hacked into his account, if he comes around please give an explanation, or some MOD could have a look into his account? I'm pretty sure he was more than 19K this afternoon, and now he has -2K, and many of his posts are being vandalized and deleted. It's too long for a steaming moment, something's wrong here.

Comment: I would say this would be better suited to ServerFault BUT it depends if the user wanted to build it or just host it.

Comment: `...since poster is a big high-rep user and should know perfectly well the rules and regulations of this site.` I totally agree, but that question is off-topic and subjective.

Comment: Isn't hosting "too localised" as well? It changes day by day *and* varies depending on where in the world you want it.

Comment: Now seems like the user vandalized his own question. Now it only states `hello i am new bee in php can you say what is best host for php`

Comment: What was the contents of the question? `hello i am new bee in php can you say what is best host for php` gives me a feeling that he forgot his account opened on his laptop and left and someone did the job...

Comment: *I would say this would be better suited to ServerFault * I see what you're trying to say but I suspect it would also get closed so fast it left scorch marks on SF too.

Comment: @Nifle He posted a nice reply here, but eventually deleted it no matter what. He might still be a bit upset and steaming, I had thought the matter was already over instead, but doesn't look the case...

Comment: This member "stereofrog" was giving me some really good help on one of my questions. I was impressed enough to look at some of his other answers and found a treasure trove of hundreds of brilliant answers that he selflessly gave to serve the SO community over the last two years. Today I noticed his username changed to "user187291" and was curious enough to investigate. Looks like he quit SO? The cold treatment that I saw given him today makes me literally sick to my stomach. He did so much good and then got crapped on by the community he loved to serve. SO has a problem and needs to fix this.

Comment: The user who vandalized his own question has some [very interesting activity](http://stackoverflow.com/users/187291/user187291?tab=activity). See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7632866/revisions), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1766767/revisions), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7484798/revisions), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7429633/revisions). Could someone be acking into this guy's account?

Comment: WTF is happening? Is it all my fault? :O Did he just lose 2K points today?? I can't believe he just got mad for this thread!! Please some MOD have a look into his account

Comment: @DamienPirsy [user187291 just offered three 500-point bounties an hour ago](http://stackoverflow.com/users/187291/user187291?tab=reputation). That explains the sudden drop in rep.

Comment: He [offered 3 500 rep bounties](http://stackoverflow.com/users/187291/user187291?tab=bounties). He could be mad and destroying his account, which I know ___no one___ here intended, or someone hacked it. At least two of his edits today appear to be vandalism, some appear to be reasonable / constructive? I don't think it's hacking, if it is , the other person is someone familiar with SO.

Comment: Yeah, but look at the questions he's offering bounties for...C'mon, it has been 9 hours since the (quite trivial, especially for a highrep user like him) "accident"...looks still strange to me.

Comment: Despite coming to his defense, I must admit that the activity on his account is very strange. It looks like it started 2 days ago at the top of page 2 on his "activity" page. So this didn't just start happening as a result of being mad that his question was closed, because it started earlier than that. The guy gives a lot of very brilliant helpful answers. If this morning's question really was such a terrible question, maybe it was the hacker that asked it?

Comment: @DamienPirsy you could always flag one of his posts and ask a mod to check the activity.

Comment: @FriendlyDev For what it's worth, [the user formerly known as stereofrog](http://stackoverflow.com/users/187291/user187291?tab=activity) appears to be systematically removing all references to his old name in other answers. It seems a bit dramatic, but I do agree that these edits are helpful in removing a lot of unnecessary noise.

Comment: I agree with @Chris, this looks like he's leaving and cleaning up behind him. Nothing to see here, if he starts to mass-delete questions and answers of his, then call the mods (Note: he has 14 questions and 777 answers at the moment).

Comment: @Padded Cell and Chris, I already flagged an answer (the most rated), flag is still under evaluation since 4 or 5 hours ago

Comment: stereofrog appears to have also taken down his website and Google Code projects. If this is in reaction to a closed question, it's the most extreme I've seen to date. I honestly hope the guy's not sick or hacked... I've done what I can to restore his posts, but can't do much beyond that.

Comment: @Shog9 thanks for restoring his post here (although the latest revision). I too feel it's a bit of an overreaction for just a deleted post; the suspect thing is the duration of this "fit of rage", which is quite unusual; he had 19K on SO, he must have seen a lot of things in his SO career, I honestly don't know what to think about this.

Comment: Again, it was clear from his activity that the strange behavior started over a day before the post that got closed on him. So it's not an overreaction from a deleted post, though the bulk of the activity did start soon after. Probably the greatest mystery I've encountered in a while.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The question is not about programming, and it also starts with, "I'm curious what you folks would recommend as a platform for a http based file hosting." The [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) has the following example of questions that should not be asked:

> there is no actual problem to be solved: "I'm curious if other people feel like I do."

As you said, the right place for asking that would have eventually been Meta Stack Overflow; I would see as acceptable a comment left under the question, even though I would not expect the users who closed the question reply to that.
Commenting on an answer left from one of the users who closed the question to ask the reason of closing is not something I would have done. The single user didn't close the question himself, but the question was closed from five different users; I think that doing the same for all the users who closed the question is not fair. I would guess the answer could be "because the question is off-topic on Stack Overflow."

To notice that, between the users who have voted to close, there is also a 100k user; therefore, the question has not been closed from users with low reputation. I don't think it  makes a difference, but at least the OP cannot complain the question has been closed from users who don't understand how SE sites work.

Answer (score 5):

For me that question is cast-iron, no questions asked, off topic for SO. There is no code in the question - there would be no code in any answer.

I would think it perhaps on-topic for Programmers, but I have a very poor intuition of what that site's commnuity thinks, so please don't quote me. Webmasters maybe?

Comment: More like Server Fault.

Comment: Definitely **NOT** Programmers. It's not *about* software development and it's the very epitome of not constructive.

Comment: "More like Server Fault" - absolutely **not** especially as written. Bad questions are bad questions, and all the SE sites should remember that the other SE sites are not your dumping ground.

Comment: @RobertMoir: Of course not! I just countered the point that it might be on-topic at Programmers. I think we can all agree that the question is below good and needs serious rewording before we can think about migrating it *anywhere*.

Comment: Fair enough, I see what you mean @Padded Cell